# Why is the bottom line in a multi-line "If"statement disappearing?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

I'm building a single "If" statement that wraps:

```
If (True) Then _
    Throw New Exception("Here is my text. " &
    "it wraps onto another line.")
```

Note I cannot do this without an underscore "_" after `Then` because I get a compiler error:

> 'If' must end with a matching 'End If'.

Subsequent lines do *not* need an underscore, although I can see how it would be best practice to have one on each line if there are any at all.

If I put the cursor on the bottom line and make any change -- i.e. hit tab to indent or add text to the string constant on that line -- then I relocate the cursor elsewhere, the bottom line inexplicably disappears:

```
If (True) Then _
    Throw New Exception("Here is my text. " &
```

This *doesn't* happen if I follow my aforementioned "best practice" and put underscores on each line:

```
If (True) Then _
    Throw New Exception("Here is my text. " & _
    "it wraps onto another line.")
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It's treating it as a single line `If`  because of the way you do the string.  string breaks should be `"fuzzy wuzzy" _ ` then new line `& "more fuzzy".` the first line should be `space + _ `

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't understand your comment.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: You continue the first part (`If`) with space +underscore  you do it different for the string leaving the `&` on the first line

Comment: `If (True) Then _ {NL}
            Throw New Exception("Here is my text. " _ {NL} 
              & "it wraps onto another line.")`

Comment: All I'm wondering is why the line is disappearing when I have perfectly valid/compilable/runnable code.

Comment: It doesnt on mine when you continue/break the string correctly

Comment: Yes, I know there are plenty of ways to make it **NOT** disappear.  Why can't you see that's not my question.  Why *DOES* it disappear when written the way I did?  "continue/break the string correctly" is a matter of opinion given my way also compiles and runs just fine.  I'm not advocating for the "wrong" way of doing things.  I'm simply trying to figure out why this is happening at all.

Comment: Because it is not a valid way to compose a single line If statement across multiple lines

Comment: And also, I pointed out in my question that it works if you use "_" on each line.

Comment: If it works, then it's valid.  How do you define "valid"?

Comment: @Plutonix So to summarize your position, what you're basically saying is "even though your code compiles and runs just fine, the reason the line mysteriously disappears is because you're code is not valid".  Do I have that correct?

Comment: You found a bug in the VS2013 editor.  It is fixed in VS2015 so no point in reporting the bug.  You already know the workaround.

Comment: @HansPassant -- Ahh, ok thanks for that.

Comment: @HansPassant thats still occurs in vs2015 update 1